# Error al cerrar formulario en Visual Basic Me.Close()

Tags: vb.net, .net, windows-forms, vb

Estoy intentando cerrar un formulario y al aplicar el método **Me.Close()**  me enviar un error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya e intendado de todo y el error no desaparece. el formulario herada  de otra ventana. Leí en otros sitios que hay que eliminar  este metodo

```vb
 'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        'If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
        '    components.Dispose()
        'End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Pero no funciono, sigue igual. En el formulario solo tengo controles de texto y botones no tengo grillas ni conexiones a base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la excepción completa

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: dataSource
>   ParamName=dataSource
>   Source=System.Windows.Forms
>   StackTrace:
>              at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.HashKey..ctor(Object dataSource, 
>           String dataMember)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.GetKey(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.EnsureListManager(Object
>   dataSource, String dataMember)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.get_Item(Object dataSource)
>              at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.a(Object , String , Boolean )
>              at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.set_DataSource(Object value)
>              at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>              at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>              at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>              at BaseForms.FormBaseGetPending.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in
>   C:\git\scientific_application_framework_2\BaseForms\FormBaseGetPending.designer.vb:line 13
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, Int32 wparam, Int32 lparam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close()
>              at frmVSwb.FormVSwbCandidateButtons.ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\git\vessel_scheduling_app_i2\frmVSwb\FormVSwbCandidateButtons.vb:line
>   554
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>              at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
>              at wcVSwinConsole.Main.Main() in C:\git\vessel_scheduling_app_i2\wcVSwinConsole\Main.vb:line 14
>              at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>              at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>              at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>              at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>         InnerException:

Comment: @gbianchi gracias ya coloque una imagen de mas detalla de la excepción

Comment: @sstan añadí una imagen de la excepción

Comment: @gbianchi
Aqui esta la imagen
https://1drv.ms/i/s!ApYgQulr-D9um9My-_V1u1Yr5N13PA

Comment: @gbianchi perdona ya añadí la exepción completa al final de la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

> En el formulario solo tengo controles de texto y botones no tengo grillas ni conexiones a base de datos.

Tal vez no lo puedas ver, pero tu formulario definitivamente sí tiene una grilla por lo menos, y de allí proviene el error.  Nota esta porción de tu error:

```
at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.a(Object , String , Boolean )
at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.set_DataSource(Object value)
at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
```

Tu formulario tiene una instancia de `GridEx`, que debe ser algún tipo de grilla.  El que tu estés bajo la impresión que tu formulario no tenga grilla me indica que tal vez en un tiempo sí lo tuvo, y luego intentastes quitarlo, o algo por el estilo.  En hacer esto, has debido corromper el código, y ahora tienes referencias incompletas a esta grilla, lo que resulta en tu error.

Tal vez convenga comenzar un proyecto en limpio. Si no, busca bien en el código fuente hasta encontrar dónde tienes referencias a este `GridEx` y elimínalo por completo.